# Execute a stage if environment variable contains specific substring

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins declarative pipeline which I am interested to be able to perform a stage only if a specific environment variable contains a specific substring(not fully equals to it, just contains it).
Does anyone got any idea on how can I implement it(maybe using the when condition if possible).

Thanks in advance,
Alon

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, in declarative pipeline you can use the [when directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) to establish a condition in which the stage will be executed.
Among the built in condition options like `triggeredBy`,`branch` and `tag` there is the **generic `expression` option**, which allows you to run any groovy code and calculate the relevant Boolean value according to your needs.
So for your case for example you can just use the groovy `contains` methods to achieve what you want, something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Conditional Stage') {
            when {
                expression { return env.MyParamter.contains('MySubstring') }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Running the conditional stage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```